# How to mock HMSLocation with jest

Tags: jestjs, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to mock the `@hmscore/react-native-hms-location` with jest. The function that one of my providers uses is `HMSLocation.FusedLocation.Native.hasPermission()`, but in one of my test I always get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Native' of undefined at call (C:\laragon\www\qmy-project\providers\LocationProvider.js:65:57)
```

I've tried to mock all the Library like this:

```
jest.mock('@hmscore/react-native-hms-location');
```

Even like this another way:

```
jest.mock('@hmscore/react-native-hms-location', () => {
    const original = jest.requireActual('@hmscore/react-native-hms-location');    
    return original;
});
```

Always is the same. Any help please?